# jquery-mobile event order and why does setTimeout set $this to undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-mobile, settimeout

I need to delay the execution of the 2nd function *crumble()* after *stackUp()* has run.

I have tried setting an event-order with *pagechange* vs. *pagebeforeshow* like this:

```
$('div:jqmData(role="page")').bind( "pagechange", function( event, data) {
   stackUp(event, data);
});

$('div:jqmData(role="page")').live('pagebeforeshow', function(event, data){
     crumble(event, data, $(this) );
});
```

Doesn't work and *setTimeout* like this:

```
$('div:jqmData(role="page")').live('pagebeforeshow', function(event, data){
     window.setTimeout(function (event, data, $(this)) {
       crumble(event, data, $(this) );
     },500);
});
```

makes $(this) *undefined*, so this also doesn't help either.

**Question**:
How can I make sure *crumble* fires when *stackup* is done?
Is $(this) becoming undefined, because it's window.setTimeout() (and not $(this).setTimeout)?
What's the correct event-order in jquery-mobile?

Big THANKS! for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `setTimeout` function makes no sense. That's not even valid syntax - `$(this)` can't be a function parameter name!

What you're looking for is:

```
$('div:jqmData(role="page")').live('pagebeforeshow', function(event, data) {
    var $this = $(this);
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        crumble(event, data, $this);
    }, 500);
});
```